# "Going live" w/ VS code and create-react-app "react-scripts build"-generated files does not get displayed in the browser, yet no errors neither

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, production-environment

Tried few flavors of my React app `production build` already - decided to start clean. Cloned the repository, `yarn install`, `yarn build` (`package.json // "build": "react-scripts build")`.

Building process seemed clean, neat & nice, so I decided to take the boy for a ride. Took the newly-created `build` folder out of the project, put it down my `Desktop`, opened up with `VS Code` and "went live" on port 5500. "Live reload enabled", it states in the console, while I laugh out loud crying as there are no errors - yet, the project is not there as well. Don't get me wrong - the generated `index.html` file is correct, the `main.456361c4.js` gets loaded in too, according to devTools Sources.

Where to start debugging?

Comment: same result with [serve](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#static-server) ?

Comment: @GabrielBleu yes - the file gets served, but there's no output to work with whatsoever. Otherwise (i.e. serving the project itself and not the build directory renders the project just fine.